# Duplicate a DataGridView on a second windows form

Tags: vb.net, object

I have a bound DGV that took a bit of work to get its columns set up.  I'd like to show a 1-row version of this identical DGV on a second windows form.  Is there a way to **programatically** place a copy on the second form.  I would adjust the height and position of the 1-row version, and create a new binding source on the second form so that I could filter the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyForm.Controls.Add(myDataGridView)`

So further explanation:

In your first for you will need to make a variable or property that contains a reference to the DataGridView that you want to access.

I'd suggest doing something like this.

```
Public Shared Property myDataGridView As DataGridView
```

then after you get it set up in the form the way you want it set up

```
myDataGridView = originalDataGridView
```

Then in the second form

```
SecondForm.Controls.Add(FirstForm.myDataGridView)
```

Will add the DataGridView exactly as it is on the first form.

**Edit**

If you are creating it in a designer, you can just either copy and past it from the original for to the second form.

Or just on the `Form.Shown` or in the `New()` of the first form set the `myDataGridView` to the `DataGridView` that you created.

Comment: I am looking for the new DGV to be a copy of the first with respect to its column setup and binding.

Comment: I understand and have done what you recommended prior to your EDIT.  My goal is to avoid having to manage the design of two objects, so I'll pass on the copy/paste.  At this point, after putting the .Add method in the form load event of the first form, nothing shows up.

Comment: the add goes in the second form, should have explained that a little clearer. So in the Second forms new, ther you will want to do the ad.

Comment: I'm sorry - I meant to say that I put it in the second form.  Your explanations are good and my problem was that the form with the .ADD method (the "second" form) was actually starting up first, so the DGV it was trying to reference had not shown up yet.  Looks like all is well now.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH.